# Could not load file or assembly ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e06fbc6124f57c43

Tags: servicestack

I encountered the following error after upgrading to ServiceStack 5.0.2

> Could not load file or assembly ServiceStack.Interfaces,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e06fbc6124f57c43

Here are the references in my project file

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Api.Swagger" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text" Version="5.0.2" />
```

Here are the reference seen from VS.

[image]

I dont have 'ServiceStack.Interfaces' reference in project file. So it is referenced indirectly somehow.

I dont know why it is trying to load an older version `4.0.0.0` when ServiceStack `5.0.2` is referenced.

So I intended to add bind rediction in app.config but then I found that is impossible.

In the binary folder, I do see `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` there. Its version is `5.0.0.0` but its `PublicKeyToken` is null. It does not allow redirecting the binding.

[image]

I tried to add a direct reference below but that does not solve my issue.

**Why it is trying to load an older version?**

Answer (score 3):

Delete your NuGet `/packages` folder and restore from NuGet again. You should only have ServiceStack **v5.0.2** dependencies, if you have any other version you still have old package references that still need upgrading to v5.0.2.

Comment: First,  there is no `packages` folders because it is `PackageReference` instead of `Reference`;  Second, in the output binary folder, I do see the ServiceStack assemblies are 5.X

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor Something's still referencing the older v4.x deps. Check for any 4.0.0.0 references in your Web.config (or a full-text search in your solution), Is this a .NET Framework or .NET Core App?

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor you should also delete your `/bin` and `/obj` folders as it can get dirty during upgrades. If that doesn't help, also try clearing your NuGet cache with `nuget locals all -clear`.

Comment: it is a .NETCORE application targeting .NET Framework, please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933196/mess-in-servicestack-version-5

Comment: ,already tried deleting,  I think the problem is because of mess in assembly families.

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor the issue is likely due to referencing the wrong packages, you need to use packages with the `.Core` suffix when running ASP.NET Core Apps on the .NET Framework.