# Mess in ServiceStack version 5

Tags: servicestack

I have a ASP.NET Core application hosted in Windows Sercice, so it is a .NETCore project but `TargetFramework` is .NET Framework.  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) Microsoft  document describes this kind of project.

The application works fine with SerciceStack.Core 1.0.44, here goes the snippet of my project file.

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Core" Version="1.0.44" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Kestrel" Version="1.0.44" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text.Core" Version="1.0.44" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.Core" Version="1.0.44" />
```

Now I am trying to upgrade to version 5.0.2, then I found there are two families of assemblies. [ServiceStack 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/5.0.2) and [ServiceStack.Core 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Core/5.0.2)

Then I tried to head on [ServiceStack.Core 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Core/5.0.2) direction and found it is totally a mess.

**First**, there is no ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.Core 5.0.2, the only one is [ServiceStack.Api.Swagger 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/5.0.2) and it is depending on [ServiceStack 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/5.0.2).

**Second**, [ServiceStack.Kestrel 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Kestrel/5.0.2) dependencies are in different family of [ServiceStack.Kestrel 1.0.44](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Kestrel/1.0.44).  You can compare the dependencies by opening the links.

- [ServiceStack.Kestrel 1.0.44](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Kestrel/1.0.44) depends on [ServiceStack.Core 1.0.44](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Core/1.0.44);
- [ServiceStack.Kestrel 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Kestrel/5.0.2) depends on [ServiceStack 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/5.0.2)

So [ServiceStack.Kestrel 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Kestrel/5.0.2) cannot be used with [ServiceStack.Core 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Core/5.0.2) any more.

Then I tried the other direction [ServiceStack 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/5.0.2) -- changing all references to the one without *Core* postfix and encountering [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932900/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-servicestack-interfaces-version-4-0-0-0-cultur) issue.

Which direction  should I go in my case?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [Run ASP.NET Core Apps on the .NET Framework](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) docs. You must continue to reference the `.Core` packages as they only contains **.NET Standard 2.0** builds. Referencing the main packages without the `.Core` suffix e.g. `ServiceStack` in a .NET Framework project will reference the **net45** builds which can only run classic ASP.NET Framework or HttpListener Apps.

In a .NET Core App you should reference the main NuGet packages e.g. `ServiceStack` as it will ignore the **net45** builds and only reference the **.NET Standard 2.0** builds.

Comment: Do you mean `ServiceStack.Core 5.0.2` + `ServiceStack.Kestrel 5.0.2` + `ServiceStack.Api.Swagger 5.0.2` ?  That does not work and generate a lot of compliation errors

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor only Kestrel doesn’t have a .Core suffix, every other package should. You can verify that it works by starting with one of the templates on the linked docs. You’ll also want to use OpenApi which is the newer successor to Swagger that implements the Swagger 2.0 spec.

Comment: Thanks @mythz, do you mean I shouldnt reference `ServiceStack.Kestrel` ?   My application was using Kestrel and it relies on `AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase` class which is missing in `ServiceStack.Core`.  How can I keep using kestrel in this case?

Comment: I am aware of `ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi` but that is a breaking change.

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor I meant there is no .Core suffix for Kestrel since it only contains a .NET Standard build. But it’s more idiomatic not to use it, have a look at source code of the [web-corefx](https://github.com/NetFrameworkCoreTemplates/web-corefx) template which is the standard example of running an ASP.NET Core App on the .NET Framework.

Comment: that does not make sense to me :(  surely I can create a new project to make it work, the thing is, I want to upgrade without changing existing code - or only changes a few lines.  So the conclusion is -- there is no way for my application to upgrade

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor I gave the link so you could use it as a reference to compare it with your code base. Of course you can upgrade - the working examples prove it, but it's not possible to tell what your issue is from here. I would start by removing all `/bin` and `/obj` folders and clear your NuGet cache, then make sure all projects are only referencing `.Core` NuGet packages.

Answer (score 1):

Finnally I get the existing project working with version 5.

First, upgrade the version to 5 as below.

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Api.Swagger" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Client.Core" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Common.Core" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Core" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Interfaces.Core" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Kestrel" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text.Core" Version="5.0.2" />
```

Then there are a lot of compilation errors as below.

```
error CS0433: The type 'IRequest' exists in both 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'
error CS0433: The type 'IRequest' exists in both 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'
error CS0433: The type 'IReturn<T>' exists in both 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'
error CS0433: The type 'Service' exists in both 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'
error CS0433: The type 'RouteAttribute' exists in both 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Verbs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Summary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Notes' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0433: The type 'ApiMemberAttribute' exists in both 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ParameterType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IsRequired' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Description' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0433: The type 'IReturn<T>' exists in both 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'
error CS0433: The type 'ApiMemberAttribute' exists in both 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587". Choosing "ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" arbitrarily.
warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "ServiceStack.Client, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "ServiceStack.Client, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587". Choosing "ServiceStack.Client, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" arbitrarily.
warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "ServiceStack.Common, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "ServiceStack.Common, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587". Choosing "ServiceStack.Common, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" arbitrarily.
warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587". Choosing "ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" arbitrarily.
warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "ServiceStack.Text, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "ServiceStack.Text, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587". Choosing "ServiceStack.Text, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" arbitrarily.
```

These errors are caused by `ServiceStack.Api.Swagger` and `ServiceStack.Kestrel`. 
In previous version, they depend on `ServiceStack.Core` whose `publicKeyToken` is null; 
but in this new version, they depend on `ServiceStack` whose `publicKeyToken` exists.

[image]

**Binding redirection cant help in this case because `publicKeyToken` is null.**

Eventually `ServiceStack` and `ServiceStack.Core` they have the same implementation on Windows in my case.

Hence, **the key to solve this issue is to change the dependencies of `ServiceStack.Api.Swagger` and `ServiceStack.Kestrel` from `ServiceStack` family to `ServiceStack.Core` family.**

The first step is to copy the assembly files into a `packages` folder in project and change the reference manner from `PackageReference` to `Reference`. After that, NuGet doesnt manage them any more and we can modify the assembly.

Now compiling the project results in different errors like below.

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'IPlugin' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'.  
Error   CS0012  The type 'IPreInitPlugin' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'.
```

They are generated by `ServiceStack.Api.Swagger` because it is trying to link to the type in `ServiceStack`. In fact the same type exists in `ServiceStack.Core` assembly whose `publicKeyToken` is null.

Now I take use of the tool [reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) to edit `ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.dll`

[image]

Select ServiceStack dependencies and clear their `publicKeyToken` as it is presented in screenshot above.

**Compile and now everything works and I dont change any code.**

The root issue is that ServiceStack changes the dependencies from `ServiceStack.Core` family to  `ServiceStack` family.

Personally I would suggest ServiceStack release another parallel package `ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.Core` 5.0.2 which depends on `ServiceStack.Core`.

Comment: That's a lot of effort to go through not use `ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi.Core` we're not publishing `Swagger.Core` because it's in maintenance mode and we're directing everyone to use the newer Swagger 2.0 support in [OpenApi](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi). But it might be easier to create a custom build of [ServiceStack.Api.Swagger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swaggeri) from source.